# Need a jQuery captcha solution for my registration form

Tags: jquery, captcha

I have a registration form that I validate with jQuery. If there are errors, it says so without page refresh. What I'm trying to do is to implement a captcha that doesn't require a page refresh to work. I tried implementing Google's reCaptcha but doing it without a page refresh is prohibitively difficult. Are there any captcha plugins for jQuery that will just return true or false right then and there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A really simple captcha like you described it is for example the [Real Person](http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html) jQuery plugin.

Generally you can find a lot of jQuery captcha solutions [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/captcha).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

"*If there are errors, it will say so without page refresh.*"

So your not necessarily looking for a captcha plugin, your looking for form validation.  Correct?  I'm assuming your referring to form errors (invalid email, etc).

Validity works really well and does not require a refresh.

http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/

**Edit:**

If I misunderstood and an Ajax enabled jquery captcha is what your looking for, this should suffice:

http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin

Comment: I already have all the form validation written. I'm looking for a captcha plugin.

Comment: My mistake.  Hopefully the plugin above will be of use to you.